# Strace. Эмулятор терминала. Не отображается взаимодействие с иксами

Tags: linux, эмулятор

Открываю новое окно эмулятора терминала konsole. Запускаю например команду `yes`. В старом окне запускаю команду и получаю примерно такой вывод.

```
sudo strace -Yyf -p $(pgrep -xn konsole) -s0

[pid  3376<konsole>] read(17</dev/ptmx>, ""..., 4095) = 4095
[pid  3376<konsole>] poll([...], 5, 8)  = 1 ([...])
[pid  3376<konsole>] ioctl(17</dev/ptmx>, FIONREAD, [4095]) = 0
[pid  3376<konsole>] read(17</dev/ptmx>, ""..., 4095) = 4095
[pid  3376<konsole>] poll([...], 5, 9)  = 1 ([...])
[pid  3376<konsole>] ioctl(17</dev/ptmx>, FIONREAD, [4095]) = 0
[pid  3376<konsole>] read(17</dev/ptmx>, ""..., 4095) = 4095
[pid  3376<konsole>] poll([...], 5, 10) = 1 ([...])
[pid  3376<konsole>] ioctl(17</dev/ptmx>, FIONREAD, [4095]) = 0
[pid  3376<konsole>] read(17</dev/ptmx>, ""..., 4095) = 4095
[pid  3376<konsole>] poll([...], 5, 10) = 1 ([...])
[pid  3376<konsole>] ioctl(17</dev/ptmx>, FIONREAD, [4095]) = 0
[pid  3376<konsole>] read(17</dev/ptmx>, ""..., 4095) = 4095
[pid  3376<konsole>] poll([...], 5, 6)  = 1 ([...])
[pid  3376<konsole>] ioctl(17</dev/ptmx>, FIONREAD, [4095]) = 0
[pid  3376<konsole>] read(17</dev/ptmx>, ""..., 4095) = 4095
```

То есть вывод состоит из последовательности системных вызовов `poll, ioctl, read`. Которые опрашивают, читают файлы (Linux всё есть файл). Но в выводе нету ничего что отображало бы взаимодействие с иксами. Прочёл эмулятор данные из устройства, а дальше ничего. Почему?

Comment: Эммм... Потому что у иксов другие pid?

Answer (score 0):

Системных вызовов много и в ваш кусок вывода просто не попало нужное. Сохраните вывод в файл и смотрите. Также strace умеет фильтровать. Делайте тоже самое только измените команду.

```
 sudo strace -Yyfe '/^write' -p $(pgrep -xn konsole)
```

Теперь вы будете видеть вызовы которые начинаются с подстроки `write`. Интересующий вас вызов `writev`. Это и есть взаимодействие с иксами посредством сокета. И да `pid`  здесь не причём. Хотелось бы чтоб люди вникали прежде чем пытаться "помогать".